# Flutter doctor unable to find bundled Java version Android Studio Electric Eel

Tags: java, flutter, macos, android-studio

When running command `flutter doctor` getting 1 issue:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on macOS 13.1 22C65 darwin-x64, locale en-IN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
[✓] VS Code (version 1.69.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
```

System config:

macOS Ventura v13.1 | Intel chip

Android Studio Electric Eel(Stable version v2022.1.1)

JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home

`java -version` command is working perfectly in terminal.

Comment: try update Android cmdline-tools  [this](https://p6-juejin.byteimg.com/tos-cn-i-k3u1fbpfcp/f0988aa1740d46b19ffc52a67c02cfa1~tplv-k3u1fbpfcp-zoom-in-crop-mark:4536:0:0:0.awebp?)

Comment: @bakboem I've latest  Android cmdline-tools

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281702/unable-to-find-bundled-java-version-on-flutter?rq=1)

Comment: Looks like with the release of Electrci Eel the directory where JRE lives changed to JRB.
Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75119315/1233565).

Comment: Just delete JRE folder: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75108707/android-studio-electric-eel-javahome-seems-to-be-invalid/75116649#75116649

Answer (score 14):

1. Go to your AndroidStudio folder

> (e.g.  C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio) in Windows

2. There you'll find the `jbr` and `jre` folder So all you need to do is to copy the content of jbr and paste the content into the **jre** folder.

Comment: Yes, I confirm that this workaround works for me (on Windows). This is documented on this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/118502) and it should work also on Mac. The bug is also open on [Google Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/247854802?pli=1)

Comment: @Ali Usama perfect solution. Worked instantly!

Answer (score 3):

For **Windows**:

The problem is because of trace of old Android Studio java folder, just delete this folder and it starts working:

C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre

The new Android Studio Electric Eel is using jbr, not jre.

---

For **macOS** as @Jayanth replied above:
If you are using macOS replace the path in .bash_profile or .zshrc

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home"
```

with

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home"
```

Answer (score 1):

For Linux:

Run the following command in the terminal.

```
$ flutter config --android-studio-dir=
```

Comment: This worked on Windows also!

Answer (score 0):

Open your AndroidStudio folder

copy All Content of "jbr" Folder into the "jre" folder.

Worked For Me.

Answer (score 0):

First Go On "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"
Copy All Data in jbr folder to jre

And

Set System Varaible (windows)
Name: JAVA_HOME
Value: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre

Then Restart your terminal

Answer (score 0):

I had two AndroidStudio folders. One was AndroidStudio other AndroidStudio1. After I deleted AndroidStudio (older) flutter doctor doesn't return warning.