# failed to load jvm dll android studio Electric Eel

Tags: android-studio

I was trying to install Android Studio Electric Eel on a laptop but after installation when I'm trying to open this error comes,
`failed to load jvm dll android studio`
[image]

I already,

Added JAVA_HOME in system variables,
Added path of Java bin folder,

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/106674#issuecomment-1381685888

Comment: Plz follow this solution it's perfect work for me *[ Follow this Steps ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75155444/android-studio-electric-eel-update-failure/75156452#75156452)*

Comment: Just delete JRE folder: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75108707/android-studio-electric-eel-javahome-seems-to-be-invalid/75116649#75116649

Answer (score 1):

try this, it's worked for me
just delete the jre folder and it starts working(restart android studio)...

C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre

The problem is because of traces of old Android Studio java folder,The new Android Studio Electric Eel is using jbr, not jre.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add your `bin` directory path in `path` **System Variable**

[image: In here]

Edit `System Variables` and add your path as follow

[image: in here]

Comment: Already did, sorry for not to mention.