# Android Studio Electric Eel Update Failure

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-electric-eel

I have updated android studio to Electric Eel and I got the following error message. What should I do ?

Error launching Studio

Failed to load JVM DLL C:\Program Files\Android Android
Studio\jbr\bin\server\jvm.dll
If you already have a JDK installed, define a JAVA_HOME variable in Computer > System Properties > System Settings > Environment Variables.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RALC.png)

I have tried changing the environment variables into different path but nothing worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have faced same issue after updating android studio version **electric eel**. it's show error like this.
[image]

After many try I found this solution. you can follow this steps.

Step 1 : You can visit this site [Official Oracle Java SE Development Kit Site](https://www.oracle.com/in/java/technologies/downloads/) and download particular JDK kit for your pc configuration. I am suggest to download this JDK version [Java SE Development Kit 18.0.2.1](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk18-archive-downloads.html) and after download you can install in your computer.

Step 2 : After Successfully installed you can go

**Stat**--> **Search**--> **Edit Environment Variable** -->
You can follow this image

1.[image]

[image]

Step 3:
Now You can Add **JAVA_HOME:** *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.2.1* (install version in your pc) Like this
[image]

and also add **PATH** : *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.2.1\bin* (install version in your pc) Like this
[image]

**Note** : You can only add user variable not system variable.

**Step 4 : Last step but main after follow these steps you can restart your pc.**

Comment: I tried Java 19, it didn't work but when I tried the Java 18.0.2.1, the version you recommended and followed the other steps you said, it worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: I was using java-11.0.17 so I had to download the latest version: java-11.0.18. Then I set up the environment variables and path to the new address. This solved the issue for me. :)